# Why my java application is not logging to the default java0.log file of java.util.logging?

Tags: java, logging

I recently installed Java 1.14 JDK on my Linux machine and started to learn Java, and I'm now stuck trying to figure out why this code is not writing to the default log file.

```
package foo;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test");

        logger.log(Level.INFO, "testinggggg info");
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "testinggggg severe");
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "testinggggg warning");
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "testinggggg fine");
    }
}
```

This code prints to the console

```
INFO: testinggggg info
Apr 01, 2020 2:45:57 AM foo.Main main
SEVERE: testinggggg severe
Apr 01, 2020 2:45:57 AM foo.Main main
WARNING: testinggggg warning
```

This is the contents of the my `/usr/java/jdk-14/conf/logging.properties` file

```
# I have omitted all comments
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= INFO

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1

java.util.logging.FileHandler.maxLocks = 100
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

When I check most of the system properties I see `NULL`, for example executing these lines in my application printing `NULL`

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit"));
System.out.println(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("logging.properties"));
```

I don't have any file in my `$HOME` directory with the name `java0.log` or `java1.log`. Why is my application not writing to these files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaly

I changed this

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

to this

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

In my `/usr/java/jdk-14/conf/logging.properties` file, and now I have `java0.log` under my Linux `$HOME` directory with these logs

BTW, changing the `logging.properties` and saving it, made the changes take effect immediately without restarting my computer, or java or something.

Comment: You should not change your system-wide logging configuration. While I don't think that something bad would happen because of that, you're expected to use custom logging configuration using property `java.util.logging.config.file` (or `java.util.logging.config.class` for programmatic configuration).

Also many people prefer log4j or logback as objectively better logging libraries, but for simple needs standard java.util.logging should be sufficient.

Comment: @vbezhenar Thank you, yes using a configuration file per application is safer, I was just trying  to understand how logging is working in Java, and I reset the `logging.properties` file again to it's original values, after it worked.